# App for extending battery life

Tags: android, bluetooth, root, battery

What are the main modifications that we can make in android that can help reduce battery consumption (from a developer's perspective).

The ideas that i could only come up with after reading these links [1](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/index.html) , [2](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/devices/managing-battery-life-for-android-devices-tips-for-users-and-developers.html) are :-

1) Reducing Brightness

2) Switching off network card when not required/Battery is low(Bluetooth, WiFi, etc)

3) Terminating unwanted Background apps ( Little bit of discussion on this topic will help a ton)

4) Minimising GSM Probing i.e. reduce the frequency at which the cellphone searches for network.

Any more suggestions will be very helpful.Methods requiring the device to be rooted are also welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote on a topic similar to this. Take a look at [Battery Safe Coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694878/battery-safe-coding/28711805#28711805). It's geared toward application development. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you that was a very nice and informative answer.

Answer (score 0):

For rooted devices, underclocking the cpu will also save energy.

Comment: Thanks.I will look into it.